# How to resore Github repo from archive using Octokit

Tags: node.js, github, restore, octokit

I have archive from github migration API. How can I restore it in different repo using Nodejs and Octokit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently GitHub's REST API [does not support](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-an-organization-repository) 'un-archiving' repositories but, apparently it is possible to do it [with GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/mutations#unarchiverepository) as pointed in [this post](https://github.community/t/403-forbidden-error-while-updating-archived-repos/171339) in GitHub Community.

[Remember Octokit has a GraphQL API client for browsers and Node](https://github.com/octokit/graphql.js/)

About unarchiving it in a different repository I'm not sure if it would be possible. Maybe you could take a look into [this Octoherd copy-repository utility](https://github.com/gr2m/copy-repository) (by @gr2m, the creator of Octokit)